# Any example of payments for omnipay?

Tags: php, omnipay

I'm trying to use omnipay to have a easy way to implement payments on my portal.
I'm interesting on paypal-express, authorize.net, mollie so far.

Payments are different each other and they need different kind of credentials and different parameters on their requests.
Can you extend your library with more easy php samples? 
I foud your library very usefull but hard to work with..

Paypal-espress has even a "return false" on it's function isSuccessful()

Comment: "I found your library very usefull but hard to work with." Yes, there is almost **no** documentation and it's annoying to read through the - as well mostly undocumented - code. :(